# How to display frame on fixed location in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, frames

I am working on a project where I am reading image file and displaying some information of that image on the frame. As of now I am displaying all the information on the frame itself due to which it is not looking good:

[image]

I thought of making the background of the information black so that it will be more readable but because of the black background, it was covering some useful parts of the image. So I thought of why not lets break the frame into two parts. On the left side, we will display all the information with black background and on the right side we will display full frame image. Something like below:

[image]

I am not sure if showing above frame is possible or not because in future I might be showing frames from the video/camera feed. If there is anyone who has already done this, then please let me know. Please help. Thanks

Below is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
import imutils

frame = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=800, height=480)

cv2.putText(frame, "Some information", (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.putText(frame, "More information", (5, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.putText(frame, "Some more information", (5, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

cv2.imshow('Application', frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
left = np.zeros((frame.shape[0], 400, frame.shape[2]), dtype=frame.dtype)

cv2.putText(left, "Some information", (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.putText(left, "More information", (5, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.putText(left, "Some more information", (5, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

img = np.hstack((left,frame))

cv2.imshow('Application', img)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain this line `np.zeros((frame.shape[0], 400, frame.shape[2]), dtype=frame.dtype)`. I believe you are creating a blank frame with width as 400. How can I also set height in this.?

Comment: I have a screen resolution of `800x480` where I am displaying this. As per your code, I am not sure why but there is a space left at the bottom which is not covered by frame.

Comment: yes, [`np.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) creates an array filled with zeros (= black), the first parameter is the height and the third parameter is the number of color channels (both taken from the `frame` picture). In order to be able to horizontally stack the side panel and the image on the right both these parameters must match. So you may want to first rescale your picture as needed and then create the side panel based on the new image dimensions.

Comment: if your screen resolution is 800x480 you may resize the image to say 550x480 and then add a panel to the left of 250x480 pixels so that the whole screen area is covered.

Comment: see for instance [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/) for different resizing options.